# add crosstalk to Quarto HTML document in R to load maps

Tags: javascript, html, r, mapbox, quarto

I want to create a basic website using `{quarto}` in R to display different maps (would be open for Rmarkdown as well). However, to not load all maps into memory of the user, I want to add a menu (dropdown) to select a map to be shown. To display the maps, I would use mapbox (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/external-geojson/). The different geojsons I want to display will be in my github. This means that the line `data: 'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson'` from the mapbox docs needs to be updated depending on the user input (for example to `data: 'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/rwanda-provinces.geojson'`). Is that somehow possible in quarto?  I think I will need a crosstalk solution like this https://timelyportfolio.github.io/quarto_tests/examples/quarto_observable_crosstalk/quarto_observable_crosstalk.html, but would have no idea how to set that up

So far this is how my page looks like (plus the mapbox token):

````
```{html}
---
title: "test loading maps"
format: 
  html:
    page-layout: custom
---

This is a Quarto website.

::: {.grid}

::: {.g-col-4}

This is where the selector would come (radio buttons)

:::

::: {.g-col-8}

```{=html}


<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Load data from an external GeoJSON file</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.11.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.11.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<style>
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 66%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" style="margin: 0 auto;">></div>
 
<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'MY TOKEN';
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map', // container ID
// Choose from Mapbox's core styles, or make your own style with Mapbox Studio
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9', // style URL
projection: 'globe', // Display the map as a globe, since satellite-v9 defaults to Mercator
zoom: 2, // starting zoom
center: [108, 4] // // starting center in [lng, lat]
});
 
map.on('style.load', () => {
map.setFog({}); // Set the default atmosphere style
});
 
map.on('load', () => {
map.addSource('earthquakes', {
type: 'geojson',
// Use a URL for the value for the `data` property.
data: 'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson'
});
 
map.addLayer({
'id': 'earthquakes-layer',
'type': 'circle',
'source': 'earthquakes',
'paint': {
'circle-radius': 4,
'circle-stroke-width': 2,
'circle-color': 'red',
'circle-stroke-color': 'white'
}
});
});
</script>
``` 

:::

:::



```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach without crosstalk and ojs.

Set up your `.qmd` like this (this adds a div that serves as a container for Mapbox and a select field with two example datasets.

````html
---
title: "Mapbox"
format: 
  html:
    include-in-header: "header.html"
---

Here's a simple example for updating data in Mapbox.

## Mapbox

```{=html}
<div id="map"></div>
<label for="data">Choose your dataset:</label>
<select name="data" id="dataselect">
  <option value="https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson">earthquakes</option>
  <option value="https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/rwanda-provinces.geojson">rwanda</option>
</select>
```
````

`header.html` contains all lines necessary for Mapbox (I've adopted the example in your question which is similar to [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/external-geojson/)). I basically add a data source with a corresponding layer and use jquery to switch the dataset on select.

```html
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.11.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.11.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>#map { margin:auto; width: 100%; height: 500px; }</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFydGluLWFybm9sZCIsImEiOiJjbGI0NjVwOTMwNTltM3JvZmtkY3VqN2p5In0.GTqfQeF5FFKqyDEdl0zfXA';
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map', // container ID
// Choose from Mapbox's core styles, or make your own style with Mapbox Studio
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9', // style URL
projection: 'globe', // Display the map as a globe, since satellite-v9 defaults to Mercator
zoom: 1, // starting zoom
center: [29.8, 5] // // starting center in [lng, lat]
});
map.on('style.load', () => {
map.setFog({});

  map.addSource('the_source', {
    type: 'geojson',
    data: 'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson'
  });
          
  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'the_layer',
    'type': 'circle',
    'source': 'the_source',
    'paint': {
      'circle-radius': 4,
      'circle-stroke-width': 2,
      'circle-color': 'red',
       'circle-stroke-color': 'white'
     }
  });
});
 
$( "#dataselect" ).change(function() {
  $( "#dataselect option:selected" ).each(function() {
        map.getSource('the_source').setData( $(this).val() );
  });
});

});
</script>
```

[image]

**Edit:**

For a side-by-side layout replace the code chunk by the following:

```
::: {.grid}

::: {.g-col-2}
<label for="data">Choose your dataset:</label>
<select name="data" id="dataselect">
  <option value="https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson">earthquakes</option>
  <option value="https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/rwanda-provinces.geojson">rwanda</option>
</select>
:::

::: {.g-col-10}
<div id="map"></div>
:::

:::
```

Comment: this works, but how can I separate the the input from the map? in this example. As in, how does the map now show on the right hand side in the wider column?